# Image color is changed after using PIL Image library

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

As a part of one task, I am downloading an image from AWS S3 and storing it in local temp folder using below code:

```
def capturing_image(img):
    res_img = []
    try:
       res_img = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
       res_img.verify()
       print("Valid Image")
       res_img = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
       b, g, r = res_img.split()
       res_img = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
       res_img = np.array(res_img)
    except Exception as ext:
       print("Invalid Image with Error: ",ext)
    return res_img

S3ActualImage_file = getS3ActualImage(image_path)
actual_image = capturing_image(S3ActualImage_file.content)
```

Issue is it is changing the color of the image. Below are my actual and downloaded image:

actual image:

[image: actual image]

after capturing image

[image: after capturing image]

How can I maintain the original color of the image?

Comment: Is the image in BGR order? why are you splitting the channels as `b, g, r = res_img.split()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are swapping the RGB - BGR channels order by mistake.

Indeed, you can notice that in your image everything red went to blue. As a rule of thumb, everytime your output looks weird because something that you would expect to be red becomes blue or viceversa, you have easily messed up with the channels order.

This happens because you assume the image is in BGR when splitting, but then you stack in reverse order.

```py
b, g, r = res_img.split()
res_img = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))
```

Merging in the same order should solve the issue.

```py
b, g, r = res_img.split()
res_img = Image.merge('RGB', (b, g, r))
```